# How to hide/show button depending on specific conditions in EJS Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I want to add a **ADMIN DASHBOARD** button to the dashboard navbar but with a condition i.e. if the user has a role of **Admin**. I have added my condition (code below) but it is not working & also I'm not getting any error in the console. I'm using **EJS** template engine & **MongoDB** for backend.

EJS CODE: *(views/dashboard.ejs)*

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #222;">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white hsize" href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <% if(user.role === ROLE.ADMIN) { %>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/admin/admindash" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-md m-1 btn-lg" role="button">ADMIN DASHBOARD</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <% } %>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a href="auth/logout" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-md" role="button">LOGOUT</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

ROUTE CODE: *(routes/index.js)*

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { ensureGuest } = require('../middleware/auth')
const File = require('../models/Files')
const User = require('../models/User')
const ROLE = require('../_helpers/role')
const { formatDate } = require("../_helpers/hbs");

// @desc    HomePage/ Landing Page
// @route   GET /
router.get('/', ensureGuest, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home'})
})

// @desc    Dashboard Page
// @route   GET /dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const files = await File.find({user: req.user.id}).lean()
        const user = await User.findOne({ user: req.params.id }).lean();

        res.render('dashboard', {
            layout: './layouts/dashboard',
            title: 'Dashboard',
            name: req.user.name,
            formatDate,
            files,
            user,
            ROLE
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/500')
    }

})

module.exports = router
```

ROLES CODE: *(_helpers/role.js)*

```
module.exports = {
    ADMIN: 'Admin',
    USER: 'User'  
}
```

**EDITED:** So when I `console.log(user)` I'm always getting the first record from my database and not the current user that is logged in

Comment: why is your const named `users` ? That is a bit confusing to me if you just want to test if a single user is an admin.

Comment: Yeah I have edited my code now !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use
findOne() because it returns a document and find() returns a cursor.

```
const user = await User.findOne({ user: req.params.id }).lean();
```

ejs code:

```
<% if(user.role === ROLE.ADMIN) { %>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/admin/admindash" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-md m-1 btn-lg" role="button">ADMIN DASHBOARD</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Yeah I changed the `users`  to `user` everywhere in the code. But still not working. I'm not getting any error which is weird and confusing

Comment: could you share with us the response of the user?
`const user = await User.findOne({ user: req.params.id }).lean();`

Comment: I have added the respone now

Comment: You should add the role to mongoose schema in order to get the role in the response.

Comment: `role: { type: String, required: true }` Yes I have added this in the schema. I figured out the issue,  `console.log(user)` is giving me the first record from the database !!